# Using Panel of TextFields in JOptionPane, DocumentListener? - Beginner

Tags: java, swing, panel, textfield, joptionpane

Edited to add the setName function:

I've been using stackoverflow for over a year to help with learning java after only about 6 hours of CS in college. You guys are the best! So getting to it...

My problem is that I've got a JOptionPane with multiple textFields. All the examples of retreiving the text from these fields only show a single textField. I could create a separate DocumentListener for each textField that handles each box separately, but it just seems that there should be a way to create one DocumentListener that can say :

*if(namebox changed)*

*edit name*

*else if(dataBox changed)*

*edit data*

etc....

Here is my code as it originates:

```
    public class HumanPlayer extends Player
    {
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class HumanPlayer
     */
    public HumanPlayer()
    {
        setName("Human " + getOrder());
    }


    @Override
    public void chooseSoldiers()
    {
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Enter name: " );
        //humans.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));


        final JTextField nameBox = new JTextField();
        final JTextField infantryBox = new JTextField();
        final JTextField scoutBox = new JTextField();
        final JTextField sniperBox = new JTextField();
        JLabel infLabel = new JLabel("Infantry: " );
        JLabel scLabel = new JLabel("Scouts: " );
        JLabel snLabel = new JLabel("Snipers: " );

        JPanel soldierPanel = new JPanel();
        soldierPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2,5, 8));
        soldierPanel.add(nameLabel);
        soldierPanel.add(nameBox);
        soldierPanel.add(infLabel);
        soldierPanel.add(infantryBox);
        soldierPanel.add(scLabel);
        soldierPanel.add(scoutBox);
        soldierPanel.add(snLabel);
        soldierPanel.add(sniperBox);

        nameBox.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new NameListener());
        infantryBox.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new NameListener());
        scoutBox.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new NameListener());
        sniperBox.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new NameListener());

        int ok = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, soldierPanel,  
                "Player " + getOrder(), JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION,  
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);        
       }

    public class NameListener implements DocumentListener
    {

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            try {
                   setName(e.getDocument().getText(0,e.getDocument().getLength()));
            } catch (BadLocationException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}

        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            try {
                setName(e.getDocument().getText(0,e.getDocument().getLength()));
            } catch (BadLocationException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();
                }               
           }
    }
}
```

Separate File:

```
public abstract class Player
{
....
private String name;
 ....

public void setName(String _name)
{
    name = _name;
}
```

Comment: can you please show use the `setName(text)` function ?

Comment: Using an if/else structure is NOT a good design. I don't really understand the question so I can't suggest an alternative. But individual DocumentListener are better than using if/else.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I actually just got it fixed using JTextField's putProperty and getProperty methods. I needed to be able to choose what data to edit, based on which box was edited. Would using individual DocumentListeners be the standard way of fixing that? With putProperty I could assign property to each textField's Document, then get that property from the DocumentListener's event. Thanks again for the help.

added code for setName(String s) to body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am understanding you correctly, you want to use one document listener and get it responding with all the `JTextFeild` data change event. Unfortunately, a `DocumentListener`'s event sources are the `Documents` to which is registered using `addDocumentListener` function, not the text component. SO the idea is to use:

1. Document's `putProperty("owner", txtFeild)`: to track the owner text field of this `Document`
2. On Document change event use `getProperty("owner")` to get the owner of the event source: document instance.
3. assigning `PropertyChangeListener` to each text field to set this property to their own document: as it is unpredictable if a new document's is set to the `TextComponent` we are using.

**Check the following code snippets carefully:**

```
    class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener{

       public void updateComponent(DocumentEvent e)
       {
            boolean valid = checkDataValidity(e.getDocument());
            JTextField txtField = (JTextField) e.getDocument().getProperty("owner");

           if(!valid)
             txtField.setEnabled(false);
           else  txtField.setEnabled(true);
       }

         @Override
         public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {updateComponent(e);}

         @Override
         public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {updateComponent(e);}

         @Override
         public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}
     }

    class MyPropChangeListener implements PropertyChangeListener{

       DocumentListener documentListenr;

       public MyPropChangeListener(DocumentListener documentListener) {
             this.documentListenr = documentListener;
       }

       @Override
       public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
           System.out.println("chaning document!!");
           JTextField txtFeild =  (JTextField)evt.getSource();
           txtFeild.getDocument().putProperty("owner", txtFeild);
           txtFeild.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListenr);
        }
     }
   //..............

   MyPropChangeListener propChangeListener = new MyPropChangeListener(new MyDocumentListener());

    jTextField1.addPropertyChangeListener("document", propChangeListener);
    jTextField1.setDocument(new PlainDocument());

    jTextField2.addPropertyChangeListener("document", propChangeListener);
    jTextField2.setDocument(new PlainDocument());
```

Comment: Very Useful Sage, you hit the nail on the head! I have implemented a sloppy version of that just before you posted, but the assurance that I was on the right track goes a long ways! Thanks again. I would vote Up, but I have to have the rep.

Comment: I will give you a +1. Keep going. You will have plenty of opportunity to upvote answers in future ;)